# Umbraco 7 Starter Kit?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have worked with previous versions of Umbraco in the past but am currently evaluating Umbraco 7 for a new project. I am looking for a more conventional approach than the default "txt" starter project that is suggested by default. Are there any other starter kits that are compatible with Umbraco 7? Preferably one that has good examples of the new MVC Razor code and  page hierarchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, the [local gov](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/starter-kits/localgov-starter-kit), or [here](https://github.com/umbraco/Starterkits), or even [here](http://bindtuning.com/cms/umbraco/theme/TheBootstrapTheme).

Have fun.